# How to use static JS with Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm creating a Bootstrap Vue application (built with Vue CLI), and there's a Javascript library I want to be able to utilize: https://nadchif.github.io/html-duration-picker.js/. I tried putting the file in /assets and then using import in the script portion of App.vue (`import './assets/html-duration-picker.min'`), but I have not been able to get the script to work, not sure why (nothing happens, no duration picker shows). As an alternative, I thought I could maybe simply load the library in the traditional way in the head of index.html. But I'm not clear what the src URL should be for a file in the assets directory. Or should it be in the assets/public directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you might as well use the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-duration-picker), if you are using Vue CLI, to save yourself a lot of trouble:

```
npm i html-duration-picker
```

[DOCUMENTATION.md](https://github.com/nadchif/html-duration-picker.js/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md) is where the installation instructions lie. While there aren't any for Vue, there are instructions for Angular, and it's fairly easy to get it working for Vue.

Just import `html-duration-picker`:

```
import * as HtmlDurationPicker from "html-duration-picker";
```

...and initalize it in `mounted()`:

```
mounted() { HtmlDurationPicker.init() }
```

[image: ta-da]

You can also run `HtmlDurationPicker.refresh();` to "update dynamically loaded input boxes." I don't think this is necessary if you use `v-model` to bind the boxes' values to data properties which update fine from either end.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lichterman-plhvz?file=/src/App.vue) you can check out for more info.

*If you do want to import it manually from `assets`, though, then what you're doing is probably fine (though you might need to add the `.js` to then end of the path); you'll just have to initialize it.*

Comment: Thanks. I tried it the way you have done and the duration picker is still not working, which suggests the problem lies elsewhere for me. Very handy to have a demo of it working successfully with Vue.

Comment: LATER: My problem was that the HTML where I used the picker was in a v-if block which was initially false. When I changed it to v-show, so it was already in the DOM, it displayed OK. Not sure what the neatest way to resolve this is, but maybe a watcher on the property tested in v-if.

Comment: Actually, replacing v-if with v-show did not properly resolve the issue. I had `<template v-if=...` which I replaced with `<template v-show=...` and the picker worked OK, but I subsequently discovered that v-show doesn't conditionally display correctly when used with template. So I changed template to div but this screwed up the formatting of the duration picker (the up-down carets were completely misplaced). It really doesn't want to play nicely with Vue!